# How can I create this background as a CSS3 radial gradient

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I want to create the radial background effect shown in the image below

[image: weather panel]

as a CSS3 radial gradient.  The trouble is that I only really discovered radial gradients a few minutes ago and my understanding of how they work is poor.  My best effort thus far is

```css
#weather
{
 height:200px;
 width:300px;
 border-radius:8px;
 background-image:radial-gradient(at top left,#667EA3 36%,#556D95 67%);
}
```

```html
<div id='weather'>&nbsp;</div>
```

which is nowhere near what I show in the image.  I suspect that I need to play with `farthest-side` rather than trying to setting `at top left` as I have done but I am not quite sure how I do that.

Comment: *I only really discovered radial gradients a few minutes ago and my understanding of how they work is poor.* --> don't you think *few minutes* is not enough and you need to do more effort to understand them and try them? google will give you a ton of documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#weather {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(at bottom right, #556D95 67%, #667EA3 67%);
}
```

```html
<div id='weather'>&nbsp;</div>
```